# Persist only column sorts and search filters with Trirand Jqgrid (ASP.NET WebForms v5.2)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I’m wondering if anyone can advise me on an issue I’m having with state persistence.

The jqGrid is used to navigate to pages to edit to each row's corresponding record, and my trouble here is that the state persistence persists the data shown in the grid at the time the state is captured, which doesn't include the links for each row. To be honest, I'm only really interested in persisting search filters and column sorting, the data persistence is more of a hindrance to tell you the truth. I know in the Gurido version of jqGrid there's an option to not persist the table data on a loadState, does this version have something similar? Any support you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is concerned?

Comment: Hi @TonyTomov , apologies, it is ASP.NET WebForms v. 5.2.0

Comment: The version 5.2.0 does not support this, but version 5.2.1 has this feature. I think you can upgrade to it, without any problems, since it is commonly a bug fix release

Comment: Hi @TonyTomov - thanks for responding. To be clear, it is the Trirand Web Forms control - they do not offer a 5.2.1 release - only 5.2.0.  We've had no response to our support request with them.

Comment: Hello @AndySw, can you please contact Guriddo Team.